# How do you read a zipped input stream without writing to a file?

Tags: java, scala, zip

I'm writing a unit test that tests functionality that creates three files zipped together and returns an `InputStream` (specifically `ByteArrayInputStream`).  I just want to take each file individually, uncompress it, and then make some assertions about the contents.  Everything I'm finding online is to write to a file, so how would I do this completely in-mem?

Here is the point I've gotten to:

```
      val zipIn = new ZipInputStream(zippedStream)

      Stream.continually(zipIn.getNextEntry)
          .takeWhile(_ != null)
          .foreach { entry =>
            val fout = new FileOutputStream(entry.getName)
            val buffer = new Array[Byte](1024)
            Stream.continually(zipIn.read(buffer))
              .takeWhile(_ != -1)
              .foreach(fout.write(buffer, 0, _))
          }
```

Comment: Instead of writing to a `FileOutputStream`, write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Then use its `toByteArray()` to get the complete bytes and process those for your assertions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of FileOutputStream, use [ByteArrayOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html). This class accumulates the data written into an array of bytes that's resized when needed. You can get a copy of the bytes it has accumulates with the `toByteArray` method.